# Query Data By Distance From the User

Tags: algorithm, firebase, geolocation, firebase-realtime-database

So, I am creating an app which works like 'Pokemon Go' in terms of getting closest data from database based on the user's location. I am using Firebase and I need to find the most efficient way to query data.

I tried to use GeoFire but it is not efficient enough since it downloads all the data then starts looping in between. So I was planning to use Firebase `queryStartingAt` and `endingAt` for longitude and latitudes in the radius I want, but unfortunately, Firebase only allows to use them once.

So I guess I use if for longitude, but now I need to find someway to limit my search results before downloading the data to the clients' devices. What do you guys recommend?

Comment: You're looking for [Geofire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire), which does precise this type of query (through the magic of geohashes, which combine latitude and longitude into a single value).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The user already tried geofire and it did not work well enough.

Comment: Geofire does server-side filtering of geohashes. If something didn't work for you, share the [minimum code that reproduces that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).